# Index count on scan + filter expression -> overcoming ProvisionedThroughputExceededException

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto

On a 10 million records dynamo db where each item has an 'epoch' time stamp attribute I'm trying to count the items between a range of epochs.
The dynamo table has a provisioned read capacity units of 1000. Each item is 5~7Kb.

The code:

```
from boto3.session import Session
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Attr

START_EPOCH = 1443657600000
END_EPOCH =   1443744000000
TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_SCAN = 1000000
F_EXP = Attr('epoch').gt(START_EPOCH) & Attr('epoch').lt(END_EPOCH)

session = Session(aws_access_key_id='access_key',
                  aws_secret_access_key='secret_key',
                  region_name='region')
resource = session.resource('dynamodb')
table = resource.Table('table name')

def scan_func(last_key,counter,scanned):
    if last_key:
        result = table.scan(FilterExpression=F_EXP,
                            Select='COUNT',
                            ExclusiveStartKey=last_key)
    else:
        result = table.scan(FilterExpression=F_EXP,
                            Select='COUNT')
    counter += result['Count']
    scanned += result['ScannedCount']
    print "Current items found {} from {} scanned".format(counter, scanned)

    if counter < TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_SCAN:
        scan_func(result['LastEvaluatedKey'], counter, scanned)

    print 'total items founs : {}, from {} scanned'.format(counter,scanned)

scan_func(None, 0, 0)
```

Even when running the scan using segments, on average after few iterations I get the following response:

> ```
> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred
> (ProvisionedThroughputExceededException) when calling the Scan operation: 
> The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded. 
> Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API
> ```

The best result I've got so far is:

> ```
> Current items found 16 from 3245 scanned
> ```

I also tried to induce a sleep of 2 seconds between each iteration to give the db space to recover and free provisioned resources, and did not work either.
Also tried to increase by 3 times the provisioned resources to 3,000 instead of 1,000 and it did some more iterations but eventually stopped.

Any ideas on how to make this work?
Other alternatives without increasing the read capacity of the table?

Comment: You could add rate limiting and [`Limit`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-Limit) to your client code to control your consumption.

Comment: Thanks @mkobit. I tried your suggestion and still does not work, it does a little bit more work before it stops and throws the provision exception.

Comment: You need to rate limit your code that is scanning your entire table. How you do that, is up to you. If the way I described above doesn't work for you, you might have make use of the [`ReturnConsumedCapacity`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-ReturnConsumedCapacity) parameter and the returned [`ConsumedCapacity`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-response-ConsumedCapacity) to adjust your consumption.